# Custom Alert in React Native / typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I need to create a custom alert in React Native, using typeScript.
I have to customize the titles and buttons, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: may be this link will help you https://www.skptricks.com/2019/08/react-native-create-custom-alert-dialog-box.html

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good choice to have a custom alert rather using `Alert.alert` as it looks very ugly in Android. 
You can use the [Modal Component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) for your requirement.

1. Make a view with flex 1 inside the modal and also use the justifyContent and  alignItems to be centerd.
2. Make a view with with your required style (This will be centered as alert). This will be your alert view. Inside that you can design your custom alert.
3. Make the transparent props of the modal true and apply background color with opacity to the flex 1 view.

You can also use some npm custom alert but it will be a good start to make the one by yourself

Answer (score 0):

React Native gives us pre build Alert dialog box to show alert messages on application screen but that Alert is old fashioned and dose not come with any modifications like adding images and customized layout. We can make our own Alert Dialog Box using Modal component, So in this tutorial we would going to Create Material Style Custom Alert Dialog Box in Android iOS React Native App with OK and CANCEL button Example Tutorial. The Alert Dialog Box is a small View windows that shows on the application screen on a specific task to going further or need additional information from application user.

here is the link you can see the example of custom alert
https://reactnativecode.com/create-custom-alert-dialog-box/

I also made a custom alert by using **Modal** here are the screenshots
[image]

[image]